# Python/Telegram При запуске бота на PythonAnyWhere, не может открыть sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, бот

Закинул файлы в одну папку на сайте, но при попытке подключения через абсолютную ссылку он выдает одну ошибку

*(unable to open database file),*

а через простое подключение, пишет

*(SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 139931923593024 and this is thread id 139931
770939136.).*

Comment: Перевод: `Объекты SQLite, созданные в потоке, могут использоваться только в этом же потоке.`

Comment: Спасибо, это я понял, хотелось бы узнать как решить эту проблему.

Comment: Погуглил вашу ошибку: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48218065/5909792

Comment: На данный момент мне не помогает, я уже изучал эту статью. импользуя метод оттуда мне пишется что бд locked

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8618328/5909792 ? В своих ботах я не работаю чисто с `sqlite3` из питона, а использую peewee (тоже с sqlite3), но с специальным классом для работы с потоками: https://github.com/gil9red/telegram__random_bashim_bot/blob/4b1895dbf44ce2700ca971dce0ac7b0edcc3e5a6/bot/db.py#L33